# Moderators shouldn't be shutting down discussions before they even begin

Tags: discussion, moderation

I posted a meta earlier today outlining why I thought Food Preservation questions should be off-topic:

[Food preservation isn't a Lifehack](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2501/food-preservation-isnt-a-lifehack)

I expected a lengthy discussion would follow, since I figured my opinion would be a bit controversial. What I did not expect was a moderator to try and shut down the discussion before it even began, by editing the post to be [status-declined](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-declined), a moderator only tag that regular users can't remove. [status-declined](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-declined) is intended for feature requests or bug fix requests, not for shutting down policy proposals by the community just because you disagree with them.

To be frank, I view this as an abuse of a moderators power. Moderators are supposed to work with the community, and enforce the will of that community. They're not supposed to use their powers to prevent the community from discussing issues, that's the complete *opposite* of what a moderator is supposed to do.

A few users have made comments asking the mod in question, Mooseman, to roll back his tag, but he hasn't replied to it yet. Since he won't reply to us in comments, I'm forced to escalate my complaint (and the discussion) to its own meta post.

Comment: I suggest this post tile should be a bit more explict: "... discussions on Meta ...",

Answer (score 8):

The tag [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) was removed by another moderator. I would have removed it now if it had not been already. Sorry about that.